# Is there a command to automatically add an entry to the .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

To ignore a file or folder in Git, you typically create a .gitignore  file and manually specify the entry. Is there a Git command, such as

```
git command-ignore [file-name | directory]
```

to automate this process by adding the entry to .gitignore?

Comment: Short answer is no. An alias would be trivial for simpler cases, but probably a lot trickier if you want to be able to handle wildcards, multiple `.gitignore` files, and so on

Comment: What's wrong with `echo file-name >> .gitignore`? This even gives you filename completion.

Comment: @larsks For a single file-name that's ok. But sometimes making an entry for folders and all the files within it involves using wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=piotrpalarz.vscode-gitignore-generator

This extension allows you to create or update an existing gitignore. Using Ctrl + Shift + P and typing gitignore you click on Java as an example and he will add a lot of entries on your gitignore file. I use it on my daily day, and works quite well.